# Frequent filesystem corruption (compute module, Raspbian)

Tags: raspbian, filesystem, compute-module

We have produced a few hundred devices based on the compute module, running Raspbian wheezy. We are seeing random filesystem corruption relatively often. We've seen it on at least 10 devices out of about 200.

The symptoms are:

- A device appears to work fine
- After powering it down and powering up
  again it suddenly fails to boot because the boot partition or the
  Linux partition can't be mounted. There doesn't seem to be a
  particular pattern to the corruption across multiple devices.
- Flashing the compute module (or in some cases running fsck) makes it
  operational again.

These are details on the partitions (these are the defaults from the official Raspbian wheeze image):

```
$ mount
/dev/root on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=185772k,nr_inodes=46443,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=38012k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=76000k)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

We are mounting the Linux partition read/write and in theory that can lead to FS corruption when cutting the power uncontrolled. But my understanding is with ext4 and data=ordered this should be very rare, certainly not as common as we're experiencing it.

Has anybody experienced similar issues or has any idea what we should look for to address this?

Comment: Do you mean a B+ or the compute module?  The B+ has a 40 pin expansion header whereas the compute module exposes all the GPIO.

Comment: How are you powering down the Pi? with a `shutdown` command or by physically unplugging it?

Comment: I meant the compute module (question edited to clarify). In the field the devices are powered up/down by plugging/unplugging the power (so uncontrolled shutdown), there's nothing else exposed.

Comment: When the device fails to boot, we try diagnose by taking the compute module out of the device and mounting it with the compute module dev kit. Sometimes the most of the time the Linux partition doesn't mount in the dev kit (sometimes the boot partition). Running fsck on the Linux partition will sometimes discover/fix various problems (no pattern discernible) but most of the time still leave the device unbootable (the corruption is too bad?).

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks. You are probably correct, there's an underlying design issue. It's more of a prototype design. In the meantime I am interested in any advice/ideas on mitigating the problem. I still think we see the problem way more often than should be expected.

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, the RPi family of devices does not provide a method to keep power alive while finishing a write operation on the SD card.

If during a power disconnection the memory card is in a write operation, there is a high chance that one or more sectors will be unexpectedly damaged.

My personal opinion is that the Raspberry Pi Foundation should take a look at this situation.

Comment: Agreed. Pull the power at the wedding moment and you'll be buying a new card. I've got several that are read only now.

Answer (score 2):

I found that using a read-only file system was a fine way of dealing with file corruption errors on classic Rpis.

In your case, you may at least try to put the `/boot` partition in read-only mode. Edit your `/boot/cmdline.txt` file to add at the end : 
    `ro`

Then edit the line defining "/boot" your /etc/fstab :

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (ro,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

If you need to write datas on the SD card, you can remount it in read-write mode with this command :

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /boot
# write some datas and re-enable protection of the SD card
sudo mount -o remount,ro /boot
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the corruption issue in my SD card. I am using Raspberry Pi2. I had this issue when I was frequently writing to sqlite db (file system). When I switched from sqlite to memory for saving my temp data the problem disappeared. Still I see services like NTP doesn't work on very few instances. But it looks more stable now. I am using the USB to power my pi.